# node.js & mongodb - scalable insert data per second

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, scalability, instant-messaging

I implemented an instant message web application. I want to saving chat message in my mongodb database. if 200 message per second pushed to my server **spent 30% one of the cores of my CPU**. I think my node.js web application hasn't good performance.
can you help me for implementing a good architecture for my instant message web application? I want to push At least 5000 message per second from client to server that spent less than %50 on of the cores of my CPU.

Thanks

this is my app.js

```
// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// Database Models ===============================================================
var Message = require('./models/message');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  // when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
  socket.on('new message', function (data) {
    // we tell the client to execute 'new message' 

    var message = new Message({text: data});
    message.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log('saved ' + data); 
    });

    socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
    });
  });

  // when the user disconnects.. perform this
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  });
});
```

config/database.js

```
module.exports = {

    'url' : 'mongodb://localhost/chatdb'

};
```

message.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    room_id: { type: String, required: false },
    member_id: { type: String, required: false },
    text: { type: String, required: false },
});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);

module.exports = Message;
```

Comment: You aren't proving enough data to solve this. What is server % cpu loads when 0 messages are sent, 100 messages, and 300 messages. With this data can approximate 5000 messages on current machine, and work backwards from there.

Comment: for 0 message per second spent 0 up to 1 percent. for 10 message per second spent 1 up to 10 percent.  for 1000 message per second spent 90 up to 100 percent